# MongoDB Exception while inserting Json Document

Tags: java, json, mongodb, log4j2

Spec : Jdk1.7, Mongodb enterprise-windows-64-3.0.12 , mongo-java-driver-3.1.0, log4j2

Abstract :
I am inserting loggings of (Customized appender)Log4j2 into MongoDB.

**Exception :**
    17:13:13.685 [main] INFO   - {"processID":"","serviceGroup":"","serviceName":""}

> org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be
>   called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is
>   STRING.

```
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:655)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:687)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:421)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:138)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:105)
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:90)
```

Question

Why is the Exception being raised while i insert my Log info which of type Json format ?

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the actual insert operation please so we can see the data you are trying to insert and how your are going about inserting it

Comment: Ok Sorry to say this problem was a Dumb mistake i had done, I was  trying to convert a JSON String to JSON String and then insert the same to NOSQL DB.... Thx for ...this was the cause.